# QDomElement::setTagName doesn't seem to work

Tags: qt

The code

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtXml/QDomElement>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QDomElement* element = new QDomElement();
    element->setTagName("feature");
    qDebug() << element->tagName();

    return app.exec();
}
```

prints simply `""`. However, as far as I can tell from [the documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qdomelement.html#setTagName) it should print `"feature"`. In fact

```
qDebug() << element->isNull();
```

prints true so something is not being set correctly. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

I'm using Qt 4.6.3 on openSUSE Linux 11.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the default constructor. You need to use [`QDomDocument::createElement(const QString &tagName)`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qdomdocument.html#createElement). The element needs to be part of a document. You cannot use it "standalone".

Here's what the documentation says for the [QDomElement default constructor](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qdomelement.html#QDomElement):

> QDomElement::QDomElement ()
>
> Constructs an empty element. Use the QDomDocument::createElement() function to construct elements with content.

By "empty" they mean [null](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qdomnode.html#isNull).